# How do I set a persistent background image for a USB drive?

Tags: finder, folders

I'm trying to change the folder background image on a USB flash drive, using the View Options panel. However, when I eject and re-insert the drive, these settings (as well as icon positions, etc.) aren't saved. In fact it doesn't look like Finder is even creating a `.DS_Store` file. How can I make this work?

Comment: Do you have a utility that deletes .DS_Store files from external HDD/USB?

Comment: Nope. Also, the same seems to be happening for regular folders on my startup disk — the settings don't stick.

Comment: What result do you get in terminal when you type: **defaults read com.apple.desktopservices**

Comment: @ioi: "Domain com.apple.desktopservices does not exist"

Comment: Try typing this in terminal now: **com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores false** then logout/login - then run the original command again and see what the output is. If you're running anything such as TotalFinder you need to exit that first.